# How to sticky element between two elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an element to "float" between two other elements by using the `position : sticky` attribute.

But I'm not getting the desired effect, and I can't figure out why.

I want `copy` to float between the bottom of `upper` and the top of `lower`.
[Here is a visual illustration of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ervmm.png)

```css
.page {
  background-color : grey;
  height : 1000px;
  position : relative;
}

.container {
  background-color : red;
  position : absolute;
  top : 35%;
  height : 300px;
}

.upper {
  height : 50px;
}

.copy {
  position : sticky;
  bottom : 0px;
}

.lower {
  height : 50px;
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="upper">
      <h1 class="hero">This is the title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">This should float between the upper and lower div</div>
    <div class="lower">
      <button class="cta">This is a CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually really close. You just need to change to use `top` instead of `bottom` in the `.copy` class.

**CSS:**

```
.copy {
  position: sticky;
  top: 16px;
}
```

Also note that the `top` value will be the position where the element becomes sticky, so if you want to scroll when it is in the middle of the window, use `top: 50vh;`.

**Update:**
It's surprisingly tricky to get `position: sticky` to work with `bottom: 0`, but [here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-babycat-h3i9vb?file=/src/styles.css).

Comment: I tried making the change in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/PDPal/pen/YzeXmZj) but it seems to be making little difference. It's only "floating" behind the `.upper` element, whereas I want it to "float" below.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but in your CodePen link, you still have the `.copy` class using `bottom: 16px` instead of `top: 16px`

Comment: Yep, I F'ed up there! 

But now I have the issue of it following the upper edge of the viewport, whereas I want it to follow the lower edge.

Comment: Ah, right, okay, I missed that before. I've updated my answer with a working CodeSandbox link.